# What is the levels column in roles in my database for PHP laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, angular, adminlte

I downloaded angular Laravel LTE template. In my database under roles there is a column called level. What is the function of this, I am new to php and laravel so I am confused.

Comment: It's using the package "bican/roles" for handling the roles. Here's a description in their readme: https://github.com/romanbican/roles#levels

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have roles that share certain privileges, so you could assign each role a different "level" so you wouldn't have to check against a ton of roles. If 10 different roles can do some action but maybe the other 5 roles can't, it would be easy to assign those 10 roles a level of `2` and keep the other 5 at level `1` so you can :

`if( $user->level() >= 2) {}`

Instead of typing 10 different roles in the below conditional

```
if( $user->is('someRole|someRole|someRole|someRole|someRole|someRole|someRole|someRole|someRole|someRole|')) {
}
```